# "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_margintop' in package 'android' " error in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, tags, android-viewpager, margin

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_margintop' in package 'android' is the error im getting in android eclipse in ubuntu. how do i fix this?

I forgot to mention i do have android:layout_marginTop="60dp" in the code as well on the same xml file but its still not working

Edit- Thanks I fixed that error now I am getting another where it says mPagerAdapter =new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments); the PagerAdapter cannot be initialised and only PageAdapter is being underlined. the quick fix says to rename in file but i dont think that works or what would i rename it to? your help is greatly appreciated!

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.util.Log;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FindPeopleFragment extends FragmentActivity {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;



public FindPeopleFragment(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_form);

    initialisePaging();

    return ;
}

private void initialisePaging() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,order_form2.class.getName()));
    mPagerAdapter =new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
```

}

here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/list_background_pressed" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" 
        android:hint="@string/first_name"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/last_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/malebutton" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="@string/femalebutton" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/phonenumber"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_line" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/affiliate_id" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/checkbox3" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/checkbox4" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your entire layout.xml file

Answer (score 2):

Breakdown of available arguments for android xml layouts:

`in` = inches on physical screen - not recommended

`pt` = 1/72 of an inch on physical screen

`mm` = millimeters on physical screen

`px` = pixels - varies in size because of all the different screen densities and sizes for Android 
devices

`dp` = `dip` = density-independant-pixels  - your best bet for most cases

`sp` = like `dp` but depends on font size preference

Your answer. make it `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"`, note that this number stays the same. It will not appear to be as much on a Tablet than it would a phone. I would advise  [on the android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

For your updated question, make sure it is `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`, case sensitive.
If not, make sure these are present in first line, and first tag as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins
This will give you a good launching point for answering your question.

Error message no doubt because you specified no units.. try "10sp" or "10dp"